# Hyphenation in Perl package names

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Line break in lines with colons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9015/line-break-in-lines-with-colons)

I have Perl package name defined as command:

```
\newcommand{\myperlpackage}{\texttt{XXXXX::YYYYY::ZZZZZ}}
```

How can I tell LaTeX to hyphen package name after double colon but without any hyphen char eg.

```
XXXXX::-
YYYYY::ZZZZZ
```

should be

```
XXXXX::
YYYYY::ZZZZZ
```

Comment: Maybe your question is answered here: [Line break in lines with colons](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9015/1235). (Possible duplicate?)

Comment: Yes, the main point of both questions is the same, but that question is more general - that's why I probably can't find it.

Comment: @jesper: So do the answers to that question answer yours?

Comment: Yes, but not as straight as this answers. I think this topic shouldn't be delete If you ask about this.

Comment: @Andrew: So what do you think?

Comment: @Hendrik: Looks like a definite duplicate to me.  In fact, I'd go for a merge.  Jesper, what Hendrik and I are discussing is just "housekeeping".  We want to be sure that anyone else searching for this will find just _one_ set of answers to look at.  No information will be lost, just put together with the already existing information.

Comment: @Andrew: Not sure about a merge; I've got no experience whatsoever with it. But I'm voting to close now.

Comment: @Hendrik: I thought that whilst there is common ground between Michael's answer and the answers on the other question (Stefan's in particular), it is different enough that it could be an useful addition to the answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually define a command `\dbr` for discretionary breakpoints like this:
`\newcommand\dbr{\disretionary{}{}{}}`. Then you can write `XXXX::\dbr YYYY::\dbr ZZZZ`, which should have the effect you desire.

To explain, `\discretionary<arg1><arg2><arg3>` tells TeX that a line break is permissible and that it should put `<arg1>` before the breakpoint, `<arg2>` after the breakpoint (in the next line), and `<arg3>` in the case that no line break is performed. See the TeXbook (page 95) for more details.